# How to position two elements on the same line with Bootstrap 4 Flex?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have these two elements: an H2 and a Dropdown button, but I haven't found a way to position them on the same line using bootstrap 4 flex.

I have this

[image]

i am trying to do this

[image]

this is my code:

```
<div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h2 class="text-center">Resultado de aprendizaje A</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown d-flex justify-content-end">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-light" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" 
           aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h p-1" style="font-size: 18px"></i>
      </button>

      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
         <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resultadoModal}edit">Editar</a>  
         <button class="dropdown-item" >
            Eliminar
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this code snippet as reference. (There are other issues you might need to solve, or you did not provide some of CSS code regarding dropdown)

Just based on the code you provide (I might be wrong), You may wrongly understand how to use bootstrap 4 properly. Don't just try to add something to your `class` as long as it looks "fine". That will cause more problems in the future.

read these two documents first to know how to use flex properly especially how the `<div>` is wrapped inside other `<div>` with `class`.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_flex.asp

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

It will make your life much easier. Happy coding!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="d-flex justify-content-between" style="background:black">
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <h2 class="text-center" style="color:white">Resultado de aprendizaje A</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown mr-3">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-light" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" 
           aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h p-1" style="font-size: 18px"></i>
      </button>
   
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
         <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resultadoModal}edit">Editar</a>  
         <button class="dropdown-item" >
            Eliminar
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```